# How to change display onclick in React?

Tags: reactjs, hide, display, visible

I am wondering how to change a display few elements from hide to visible in React. I have 4 section and for each section button. Start section has start button, About section has about button, Skills section has skills button and Contact section has contact button. How to make it when im clicking Start all others sections get instantly display: none and only Skills section is visible? By clicking About button, others get hide (none) and only About is visible? Etc to others sections.

I know that i have to make a handleonclick but idk how.
Should it work with state?

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

    class Start extends Component {
        render() {
          return (
              <div className='start'>
              </div>
          );
        }
      }

    class About extends Component {
        render() {
          return (
            <div className='about'>
            </div>
          );
        }
      }
      
      class Skills extends Component {
        render() {
          return (
            <div className='skills'>
            </div>
          );
        }
      }
      
     class Contact extends Component {
        render() {
          return (
            <div className='contact'>
            </div>
          );
        }
      }
      
    class Buttons extends Component {
        render() {
          return (
            <div className="buttons">
              <button>Start</button>
              <button>About</button>
              <button>Skills</button>
              <button>Contact</button>
            </div>
          );
        }
    }

    class App extends Component {

      render() {
        return (
          <div className="App">
            <Buttons />
            <Main />
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
    registerServiceWorker();
```

```html
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Did you try to place your `handleOnClick` somewhere, or even create one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a state `activeSection` in the parent container called `App`. Then, pass it as a props to the child section components, `About`, `Skills` etc. Also add a method `handleToggleSection`, which you can call on click to the buttons and change the state `activeSection` to that corresponding section name. Inside all section components, `About`, `Skills` etc., check the current section name. If the name matches, then return the html or return `null`. Remember, when you return `null`, that component don't mount. If you want to keep the components mount regardless they are visible or not, then u need to use css classes like `show`, `hide` etc.

Here is the demo.

```js
// import React from "react";
// import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class Start extends React.Component {
  get show() {
    return this.props.activeSection === "start";
  }

  render() {
    if (this.show) {
      return <div className="start"> Start </div>;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}

class About extends React.Component {
  get show() {
    return this.props.activeSection === "about";
  }

  render() {
    if (this.show) {
      return <div className="about"> About </div>;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}

class Skills extends React.Component {
  get show() {
    return this.props.activeSection === "skills";
  }

  render() {
    if (this.show) {
      return <div className="skills"> Skills </div>;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}

class Contact extends React.Component {
  get show() {
    return this.props.activeSection === "contact";
  }

  render() {
    if (this.show) {
      return <div className="contact"> Contact </div>;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}

const Buttons = ({ onToggle }) => (
  <div className="buttons">
    <button name="start" onClick={onToggle}>
      Start
    </button>
    <button name="about" onClick={onToggle}>
      About
    </button>
    <button name="skills" onClick={onToggle}>
      Skills
    </button>
    <button name="contact" onClick={onToggle}>
      Contact
    </button>
  </div>
);

const Main = ({ activeSection }) => (
  <React.Fragment>
    <Start activeSection={activeSection} />
    <About activeSection={activeSection} />
    <Skills activeSection={activeSection} />
    <Contact activeSection={activeSection} />
  </React.Fragment>
);

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      activeSection: ""
    };

    this.handleToggleSection = this.handleToggleSection.bind(this);
  }

  handleToggleSection(e) {
    const { name } = e.target;
    this.setState(() => ({
      activeSection: name
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Buttons onToggle={this.handleToggleSection} />
        <Main activeSection={this.state.activeSection} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for response. Any idea how to make it with some animation on show and hide? Some simple 1sec hidding and showing. ComponentDidMount should i use?

Comment: But how to make it that Start content is always running when u enter to the website or refresh website?

Comment: @Mat_-_ Ask a new question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52226297/react-site-changing-content-by-clicking-buttons-how-to-make-start-section-alw

Answer (score 0):

You can use [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html).

```
selectSection = section => {
  this.setState({ section })
}

render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Buttons onClick={this.selectSection} />
      {this.state.section === "start" && <Start>}
      {this.state.section === "about" && <About>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Also, instead of the `if` you can use `switch`.